# Upload Image To WCF Using Postman

Tags: c#, wcf, multipartform-data, postman, wcf-rest

I have created a service to upload image using WCF Rest and I want to test my service through Postman. Below is my code:

***IService1.cs***

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;
using System.Text;

namespace WcfImageUploadService
{
    // NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the interface name "IService1" in both code and config file together.
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IService1
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "/UploadFile?fileName={fileName}",        
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped)]
        void UploadFile(string fileName, Stream stream);
    }
}
```

***Service1.svc.cs***

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;
using System.Text;
using System.Web.Hosting;

namespace WcfImageUploadService
{
    // NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the class name "Service1" in code, svc and config file together.
    // NOTE: In order to launch WCF Test Client for testing this service, please select Service1.svc or Service1.svc.cs at the Solution Explorer and start debugging.
    public class Service1 : IService1
    {
        public void UploadFile(string fileName, Stream stream)
        {
          byte[] bytes =  ReadFully(stream);
          // Save the byte[] into the database.
        }

        public static byte[] ReadFully(Stream input)
        {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[16 * 1024];
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                int read;
                while ((read = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                {
                    ms.Write(buffer, 0, read);
                }
                return ms.ToArray();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

***Web.config***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="WcfImageUploadService.WebHttp" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" transferMode="Streamed" sendTimeout="00:05:00">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
          <security mode="None" />
        </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
        <service behaviorConfiguration="WcfImageUploadService.FileUploadServBehavior" name="WcfImageUploadService.Service1">
        <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="web" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WcfImageUploadService.WebHttp" contract="WcfImageUploadService.IService1">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="web">
          <webHttp />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="WcfImageUploadService.FileUploadServBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
    <!--
        To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
        Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
      -->
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
        <defaultDocument>
            <files>
                <add value="Service1.svc" />
            </files>
        </defaultDocument>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

***Postman Request***

[image]

My issue is that I am getting `Null` in FirstParam(fileName) and for SecondParam(Stream) get the below exception:

```
length = 'stream.length' threw an exception of type 'system.notsupportedexception'
```

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: try to set the request ContentType and ContentLength in header

Comment: I am using multipart/form-data as ContentType